# Extract continuous sections of text from txt file

Tags: python

I have a text file that has continuous sections of questions and answers. For example:

```
Q1: some lines of text.
Answer: some lines of text.
Q2: some lines of text.
Answer: some lines of text.
```

I want to extract the questions and answers from the text file, and put them in a csv file with two columns (Questions and Answers), where the questions and answers go into their respective columns.

This is the code I have now (still rudimentary):

```
for line in file:
    if line.strip() == 'Answer :':
       print(line)
       break
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('Q'):
       break
        print(line)
```

But this prints out only the first instance of the Answer. What do I do?

This is an example of the file:

```
Q1: What is the piston rod and the connecting rod?
Answer:
Piston Rod
A rod which is connected to the piston and the connecting rod is called piston rod. 
Connecting Rod
The intermediate element between piston rod and crankshaft is the connecting rod. 

Q2: State the constructional features and material requirements of connecting rod.
Answer: 
1. The cross-section of connecting rod is I-section and the rods should be designed long, inorder to satisfy our need and
requirement.
2. The rods should have high strength and should not fail, when axial loads are applied on them.
```

This is a screenshot of part of the file:

[image: screenshot]

This is an example of the question and answer format in the text file:

```
Q1. 
What is the piston rod and the connecting rod? 
Answer :  
Piston Rod

A rod which is connected to the piston and the connecting rod is called piston rod. It transmits gas pressure developed by 
the fuel or steam to the crankshaft through connecting rod. One end of piston rod is attached to the piston by a tapered rod with a 
nut and the other end is joined with the connecting rod, through a crosshead by a cotter-pin. These ends are having no revolving 
movement and hence, they are considered as fixed ends.
Connecting Rod

The intermediate element between piston rod and  crankshaft is the connecting rod. It consists of a small end which acts as 
a connection for piston rod and a big end, that is usually split to accommodate the crank pin bearing shells. When the fuel force 
is transmitted from piston rod to crankshaft, the connecting rod is also subjected to alternate tensile and compressive forces. The 
compressive load is taken as the design load for the connecting rod, similar to the design of piston rod.
Q2. 
State the constructional features and material requirements of connecting rod.
Answer : 
1. 
The cross-section of connecting rod is I-section and the rods should be designed long, inorder to satisfy our need and 
requirement.
2. 
The rods should have high strength and should not fail, when axial loads are applied on them.
3. 
Connecting rods are made up of carbon steels or alloy steels of molybdenum and chromium, as these materials have high 
tensile and compressive strengths.
Q3. 
Write about the forces acting on the connecting rod.
OR

Explain the various types of stresses induced in the connecting rod.
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include an example of the text file? A series of two questions and answers would really help. There a lot of nice ways to breakup a text file, but it will depend largely on the formatting of your text file.

Comment: Which is the format of the text file? Plain text files do not have bold characters.

Comment: It was actually a pdf file that I converted to text using PyMuPdf library. But the screenshot was from the pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the full question text as a key dictionary is not needed. Then you need to know it in advance to recover the answers.
You could use two separate lists or dictionaries, one for questions, one for answers. If you use lists, just be sure that question and corresponding answers are at the same index. If you use dictionaries, use the same key (could just be a progressive number) in each dicitionary for the question and the corresponding answer.

Here an example with two dictionaries:

```
import re

questions = {}
answers = {}

c = 1
scanquestion = True
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as ff:
    for line in ff:
        if re.search(r"^Q\d+", line) is not None:
            scanquestion = True
            questions[c] = line
        elif 'Answer' in line:
            scanquestion = False
            answers[c] = ""
            c += 1
        elif line == '\n':
            pass
        else:
            if scanquestion:
                questions[c] += line
            else:
                answers[c-1] += line

print(questions)
print(answers)
```

`questions[1]` is the first question, `answers[1]` is the corresponding answer.

**EDIT after comments and edit of question**

After seeing the screenshot and reading the comments, I think you do not have any new lines between answers and questions.
I've edited my answer. I use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to search for "Q1", "Q2" at the beginning of a line to identify a new question, and do not make any assuptions on presence / absence of empty lines (if present, they are skipped).

Comment: I'm getting: KeyError: 1 (pointing at the line: questions[c] += line)

Comment: Do all your questions start with "Q1", "Q2", etc? If not, that's the reason. I've edited my answer to be more general.

Comment: All the questions started with "Q1", "Q2", but they're in a string format, and your edit no longer gave the error. But it's not giving me the result I want. For example, when i tried to print(questions[1]) and print(answers[1]), it gave me the whole text in the file, just not in a dictionary format. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: That's strange. I tried it and it separates questions and answers correctly. Are you sure your `myfile.txt` follows the format you posted in the question? Is there one empty line between each question-answer couple?

Comment: I guess. Let me add a screenshot of part of the file. I edited my original question and added it there.

Comment: Sorry, you tried to edit my answer. Better edit the original question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I did not notice.

Comment: I'm sorry for being this clumsy. I've edited the original question now.

Comment: @adomzy I've edited again after seeing the screenshot.

Comment: I'm getting the same "KeyError: 1" error I was getting before. I'm sorry for disturbing this much.

Comment: Could you copy paste in your question the content of the the text file converted? It's likely that there is ore or more extra characters before the "Q" and the regex does not match.

Comment: I have added an example of the way the questions and answers look in my text file.

Comment: I tried using the updated text file, I do not get the KeyError. Could you tell me where exactly the KeyError happens? (which line of code). I'm very curious now to understand what is going on.

Comment: It happens on this line: "questions[c] += line".

Comment: I tried changing it to "questions[c] = line", and it started working. But some of the questions with more than one line had some lines missing. For example, Q3 (in my question above), showed only the last line that starts with "Explain...". The other lines of that question were missing in the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that is expected. `+=` concatenates the line to the previous ones. What I cannot understand is why it misses the first line. The only explanation I can give is that in some cases the beginning of the question does not follow the pattern "Q" plus number. Try to `print(c)` to the console just before `questions[c] += line` You can understand which question fails to be recognized and see in the text file if there are, for example, other characters before the Q.

Comment: I think the code only prints out the line in a question that's just before the Answer. I tried adding another line to Q2, and it printed out just the new line I added. I need it to print out everything between the question and answer.

Comment: That is because you changed `questions[c] += line` to `questions[c] = line`. Leave the `+=`. You need to understand why it fails to recognize the beginning of the question. As far as I understand, it does not enter in the first `if` statement when it should. But on my machine, with the sample code you provided, my code works.

Comment: I just found out why it was not working. The beginning of the text file I'm using was not the beginning of the text I gave as example (I just copied the important part). So when I deleted that part from my text file (so that Q1 was the actual first line), it started working perfectly. Thanks so much man! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: Ah! That's it! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your text file as:

```
Q1 : What is your name?
Answer: Joe

Q2: What is your last name?
Answer: Joe Joe
```

Now to create a dictionary we can do:

```
df = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
df = df.readlines()
ques = []
ans = []
for items in df:
    if "Q" in items:
        ques.append(items)
    elif "Answer" in items:
        ans.append(items)
dictionary = {q:v for q, v in zip(ques, ans)}

print(dictionary)
> {'Q1 : What is your name?\n': 'Answer: Joe\n',
 'Q2: What is your last name?\n': 'Answer: Joe Joe'}
```

I am also assuming that each question is followed by it's answer. If not this might need some update

Comment: When I tried your code, { 'Q1. \n': 'Answer : \n', 'Q2. \n': 'Answer :  \n'}. And I don't know if I'm going about this the wrong way, but what I really intend to do is to classify all the questions and answers and insert it into a database (e.g mongodb). I read that that's usually done by inserting as json, that's why I decided to use this method. If there was a better method, please I would like to know.

Comment: Also, some of the questions and answers are contained in more than one line. But your code seems to print the questions and answers next to them.